# failed to load resource file sqlcmd.rll

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a sql script file which is 1.5GB
i want to run it but i cant use it using SQL Management Console, cause it can't load the file. I came up to the solution that run the query with SQLCMD utility but when i want to execute the file it returns (Failed to load resource file SQMCMD.rll)

sqlcmd -s (local) -i C:\myScript.sql

anyone knows what is the problem and how i can run this large script file ?

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem, and I have solved.

In my case the problem was I had installed more than one version of SQL (2005, 2008, 2012), and I had uninstalled the two first ones, so at this moment I only have the Sql Sever Express 2012.

After playing a lot of minutes I discovered that old installations left his respective sqlcmd.exe files in my machine, but the uninstall process removed the corresponding rll file.

When I hit in the cmd window the sqlcmd it seems the system tries to run the sqlcmd for one of the old sql installation.

Then I went to the folder of the installed version and that works.

It is (in my case, in your case you can find the file sqlcmd.exe):

1- **cd C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn**

Inside that folder, then

2- **SQLCMD -d databaseName -i C:\MyScripts\specificScript.sql**

And that did the trick!

Comment: As it turns out the whole subdirectory of an old 2008 installation was still there. So this problem may also occur for other binary tools.

Answer (score 2):

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=228de03f-3b5a-428a-923f-58a033d316e1&displaylang=en

I'd download the sqlcmd installer and run it - see if that fixes you up.

It's under "Microsoft SQL Server 2008 Command Line Utilities".

The installer should create that file and you'll be set.  You could also try to run osql, which is the older command line SQL utility.

Edit:

---

Try [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sqlexpress/thread/94f56937-bd6f-45d7-ac2f-a5a0c8a57c99):

Please check the permission on the sqlcmd.exe and sqlcmd.rll and make sure the user has the read&execute permission on them.  You also could specify the full path of the sqlcmd.exe in the command, such as:
"C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\sqlcmd.exe" -L

Comment: The file exists in C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\Resources path but sqlcmd can't recognize it. i've already do what you've say but nothings changed

Comment: download link broken

Answer (score 0):

I just had this problem on SQL Server 2008 R2. Reinstalling the Command Line Utilities from the [Feature Pack](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=16978) is what did it. The trick is if you are on 32-bit only install the x86 package, but if you are on 64-bit install both the x86 and the x64 package. The reason for this being is that some SQL Server tools are only 32-bit which means that both `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn` and `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn` are in your PATH variable in order to ensure all of the tools are accessible, which means either of them could be run, therefore both of them need to reinstalled to ensure you have them run properly.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the issue arised after migrating from SQL Server 2008 R2 to SQL Server 2012. 
The problem was pretty simple. It was the path. Just correct your SQL Server path in the System path pointing to the new directory.

Answer (score 0):

I got a variant of this error in an Linux installation of the [MS SQL Server CLI for Linux](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-setup-tools?view=sql-server-linux-2017), which stated,

```
# bcp
Unable to load BCP resource DLL.  BCP cannot continue.
# sqlcmd       
Unable to load SQLCMD resource file(s)
```

I found that I had not followed the installation direction exactly, in that rather than modify the system PATH to add the installation directory (/opt/mssql-tools/bin), I had used 'install' to copy the binaries to /usr/local/bin without the corresponding /opt/mssql-tools/share directory.

```
for I in /opt/mssql-tools/bin/*; do install $I /usr/local/bin; done
```

When I removed those copies and did `export PATH="$PATH:/opt/mssql-tools/bin"` as the instructions show, then it worked.

```
# bcp
usage: bcp {dbtable | query} {in | out | queryout | format} datafile
[...]
# sqlcmd
Microsoft (R) SQL Server Command Line Tool
Version 17.1.0000.1 Linux
[...]
```